# Combinatorics question - find how many different ways

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Entrapta has $20$ clones of her best friend, Hurdak. Each of the clones can be dressed either in a hat, or in a shirt, or in pants (exactly one clothing detail per clone) and each of the clothing can be painted in one of six colors (blue, white, black, red, yellow or pink).

$1)$ In how many different ways can Entrapta dress up all the clones so that exactly two clones get the same item of clothing that is painted the same color?

$2)$ In how many different ways can Entrapta dress all the clones so that at least two of them will be dressed in the exact same item of clothing?

I'm stuck here, don't know even how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-)$ Let say that two clones exactly dressed with hats whose colors same, there are $6$ choice for it.Then,the rest cannot be dressed with hat ,so $2$ choice remains for them such as shirt and pants with six colors.

$\therefore C(6,1).(C(2,1).C(6,1))^{18}$

However , we should multiply it by $3$ because the first two clones may have been dressed with pants or shirt.

$\therefore 3. C(6,1).(C(2,1).C(6,1))^{18}$

$2-)$ HINT: All situations - all clones dressed with different